Python - Concatenate data attributes of a class
I have a class
class Phone:
    def __init__(self, brand, name):
        self.brand = brand
        self.name = name

phone = Phone("apple", "iphone3")

So I want to concatenate both data attributes to result like
"apple; iphone3"
I would like to avoid
phoneData = phone.brand + ";" + phone.name

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Any reason why you want to avoid phoneData = phone.brand + ";" + phone.name ?

In a future, phone class is getting more attributes and I would like to avoid fixing each time.

No way to avoid it. But you can override __str__ and/or __repr__ method of  Phone:
class Phone:
    def __init__(self, brand, name):
         self.brand = brand
         self.name = name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.brand};{self.name}'


phone = Phone("apple", "iphone3")

print(phone)

output:
apple;iphone3


And a bit of a hack that also can be used (but I wouldn't recommend it, it's more for educational purposes):
phone_data = ';'.join(phone.__dict__.values())

with the same output.

Thanks very much. Just a question. Does your version upgrade the code? Or is it only a matter of preference?
